# Unable To Upload multiple Photos in Table in Laravel any help would be apricated

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

this Is the Model which I am using for inserting photos in Photos Table by use of MorphMany Realtions in laravel in Object Model

```
public function photos(){ return $this->morphMany('App\Photo', 'photoable');}
```

photable function in Photo model

```
 public function photoable(){

return $this->morphTo();

}
```

form for adding photos.

```
<input type="file" name="objectPictures[]" id="objectPictures" multiple><br>
```

here I am inserting the Object in objects table along with Photos in Photos table. Object inserted successfully but photos are not inserting.

```php
public function saveObjectby(Request $request)
{
    $inputs=request()->validate([
        'name'=> 'required|min:8|max:255',
        'description'=> 'required',
    ]);

    $object = new TouristObject();

    $object->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $object->name = $request->input('name');
    $object->package_id = $request->input('package_id');
    $object->description = $request->input('description');
    $object->save($inputs);

    if ($request->hasFile('objectPictures'))
    {
        $this->validate($request, \App\Photo::imageRules($request,'objectPictures')); 
        foreach($request->file('objectPictures') as $picture)
        {
            $path = $picture->store('objects', 'public');
            $photo = new Photo;
            $photo->path = $path;
            $object->photos()->save($photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the `javascript` and `jquery` tags from your question, since they seem unrelated.

Comment: Any reason why you used a morphable relation here?

Comment: I had Added on ly Php laravel and eloquent Tags here I dont see any where javascript tag

Comment: Hello Bromberg Thansk for showing Interest to solve my problem . Actually I am using One table for adding all other realted objects photos such as user photo, post foto many others .that's why i did use that polymorphic relations